# Parsing Data for android-L failed

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop

i have update my sdk for L Developer preview. and i am not able to load my `layout` for `API 20`

my JDK compilence and .class file compatibility is 1.7.

here is snap

1)

[image]

2)

[image]

so may i have to change any compile level?

Comment: Make sure you are running Eclipse/Android Studio with JDK 1.7.

Comment: yes i am using JDK 1.7 please check above screen shot..

Comment: No, the question is: Are you using JDK 1.7 for *running your IDE*. If you are on Windows and have multiple JDKs/JREs installed it might use JDK 1.6 which causes this error.

Comment: Not going to work on a Mac, as Apple is still at JDK 1.6

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please, note this Android icon in the upper side of the screen

[image: Android icon]

This icon is in the upper side of this screen:

[image: Screen which displays the API version to render the code]

Probably it's displaying the number 20. This is the selection to use the API 20 to render the window. Change it to 19, or 20W (not 20L). It'll fix the problem.

[image: API 19 selected]

Comment: What version of eclipse are you using ? I dont see the icon in my IDE.

Comment: I'm using ADT (Android Developer Tools) version 23.0.0.1245622, downloaded from http://developer.android.com

Comment: This not solve the problem permanently. At every boot, the problems returns. How i can solve the problem permanently?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem on my Mac OSX and resolved by downloading and installing jdk 1.8 from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html). Hopefully your problem will be solved